# How to remove limit in creating folder in Google Drive through Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to create a bulk of folders in my google drive using scripts in google spreadsheet. Fortunately, I have found the script I have been looking for. However, upon executing the script, it gave a notice that (I forgot the exact message) I have reached the maximum number of folders to create. So it just stops. Here is the code. I hope someone could tell me how can I or what should I change for it to create folders as required.

````
function onOpen() { //This is the new standard script for the onOpen trigger that creates a menu item.
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('GDrive')
  .addItem('Create new Folders', 'crtGdriveFolder')
  .addToUi();
}



function crtGdriveFolder() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var levelInput = Browser.inputBox('input Level', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);  
  var Level =  levelInput * 2 + 1; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(3, Number(Level)-1, numRows, Number(Level)); //startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var parentFolderID = new Array();

  for(var i in data)
    {        
    parentFolderID[i] = data [i][0];
    if (data [i][0] == "")
      {
      parentFolderID[i] = parentFolderID[i-1];
      }  
    }
    
    
   for(var i in data){
    if (data [i][1] !== "")
      {
      var theParentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderID[i]);
      var folderName = data[i][1]; 
      var theChildFolder = theParentFolder.createFolder(folderName);   
//      Utilities.sleep(100); 
      var newFolderID = sheet.getRange(Number(i)+3,Number(Level)+1);
      var folderIdValue = theChildFolder.getId();
      newFolderID.setValue(folderIdValue);
      
      var addLink = sheet.getRange(Number(i)+3,Number(Level));
      var value = addLink.getDisplayValue();
      addLink.setValue('=hyperlink("https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/folders/'+ folderIdValue +'","' + value + '")');      
      }
    }
  }```


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKKLr.jpg
````

Comment: You might try putting the utilities.sleep() back into the code.

Comment: How many folders do you want to create?